# How to store Jboss web service requests

Tags: java, web-services, jboss6.x

I'm using Jboss 6 and need to store any incoming/outgoing web service requests(soap). 
I know Jboss allows you to log any web service messages, but I want to store them in a database without going through a log file. Any idea how I may do that? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Jboss. But I'd think that you could treat these requests just like any application data. This means you could map them to database via a persistence API.